# Access “jekyll-assets” hash digests via Liquid

Tags: jekyll, liquid, jekyll-extensions

I'm using the `jekyll-assets` plugin to bundle my site assets and refer to them via a CDN url, which is working well! However I am using Content Security Policy on my site, and I would like to be able to whitelist the files individually by referring to their hash values , rather than whitelisting the entire CDN domain.

Since `jekyll-assets` already knows the hash of this file (it calculates one for cache-busting reasons in the output filename and uses a different one for Sub-Resource Integrity), can I get access to this hash (ideally a SHA256 hash!) through the use of Liquid so that I can update the .htaccess/web.config/whatever file to change my CSP headers as the `site.js` and `site.css` files evolve? Something that I could use like `{{ assets["site.css"].sha256 }}` in my `web.config` template so I can generate the appropriate CSP header at build-time would be awesome.

TL;DR: I'd love to access each file's SHA256 hash via Liquid preprocessing template tags, in much the same way you can already access properties like the already documented and supplied properties like filename and basepath and whatnot. Is this possible?

Comment: If you have a sha somewhere, you will find it with a `{{ assets["site.css"] | inspect }}`